# Primefaces 4.0 <p:menubar/> broken with HTML5 doctype <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, doctype

I am migrating my primefaces application to HTML5 and I realized something weird when I changed the [doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) to HTML5.

I have `<p:menubar/>` working perfectly with XHTML doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="menuForm">
            <p:menubar id="appMenu">
                <p:menuitem value="Celulares" url="#{menuMB.toMeusCelularesIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}" />

                <p:submenu label="Celulares (Admin)" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}">
                    <p:menuitem value="Titulares (Corporativo)" url="#{menuMB.toCelularTitularIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Agregados" url="#{menuMB.toCelularAgregadoIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                </p:submenu>

                <p:menuitem value="Ajuda" url="example.com" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}"  target="_blank"/>

                <p:menuitem value="Sair" url="#{menuMB.toLogout()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}" />
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

However, when I only change the page doctype to HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), the menu broke. Take a look into my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="menuForm">
            <p:menubar id="appMenu">
                <p:menuitem value="Celulares" url="#{menuMB.toMeusCelularesIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}" />

                <p:submenu label="Celulares (Admin)" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}">
                    <p:menuitem value="Titulares (Corporativo)" url="#{menuMB.toCelularTitularIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Agregados" url="#{menuMB.toCelularAgregadoIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                </p:submenu>

                <p:menuitem value="Ajuda" url="example.com" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}"  target="_blank"/>

                <p:menuitem value="Sair" url="#{menuMB.toLogout()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}" />
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Here the screenshot:

[image: Broken menu]

Comment: I don't think it's the issue of `<DOCTYPE>` because primefaces showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf renders with `HTML5` doctype

Comment: Am I missing something? I have tested on Firefox, Chrome and IE. Same behavior.